# what is a disagreement set in nominal unification?

Tags: programming-languages, unification

In unification, for example set $s=\{ f(a,Y),f(X,d) \}$ has a disagreement set $\{ (a,X),(Y,d) \}$, since these two elements does not match on their fields. simply speaking that is a set disagreement set and in unification finds terms for $X$ and $Y$ to make disagreement disappear, so unifies.

I got a question about nominal unification.

[source: nominal unification](http://www.gabbay.org.uk/papers/nomu-jv.pdf)

Definition 2.5. The disagreement set of two  permutations $\pi$ and ${\pi}^{'}$ is the set of atoms $ds(\pi,\pi^{'})=\{a|\pi.a  \neq \pi^{'}.a \}.$

It gives an example. here it is

$\{a \#X,c \#X\} \vdash (a\,c)(a\,b).X \approx (b\,c).X$

saying the disagreement of the permutations $(a \,c)(a\,b)$ and $(b\,c)$ is $\{a,c\}$.

I don't get how that disagreement set is obtained.

can anyone explain to me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just saying "I didn't understand" probably isn't enough, because it doesn't give us any indication why you didn't understand.  I worry someone will try to explain and you might say you didn't understand that explanation either.  The more you can give us to work with, the more likely that someone will be able to give you a useful answer.  Can you tell us what you *did* understand and why you are confused?  When you try to compute the disagreement set, what do you come up with?

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). Thank you!

Comment: @D.W. I improved the question.